# Conditions for the map of sheaves $F\to F\otimes_{\mathcal O_Y}f_\ast \mathcal O_X$ to be an isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $f:X\to Y$ be an *immersion* of locally noetherian separated schemes, for instance (not necessarily reduced) varieties over a field $k$. We can us assume $Y$ is affine.

Let $F$ be a quasi-coherent sheaf on $Y$. There is a canonical map 
$$
F\overset{u}{\longrightarrow}F\otimes_{\mathcal O_Y}f_\ast \mathcal O_X.
$$
I wonder under what conditions on $f$ or on the sheaf $F$ the map $u$ is an isomorphism.

---

1. If $f$ is a closed immersion, then $u$ is surjective. Even in simple cases, like the thickening of a point $f:X=\textrm{Spec }\mathbb C\to Y=\textrm{Spec }\mathbb C[\epsilon]$, I do not seem to get beyond surjectivity.
2. If $f$ is an open immersion, I have the following example in mind. Suppose $f$ is the immersion of a distinguished open set, namely $f:X=\textrm{Spec }B_h\to Y=\textrm{Spec }B$ for some $h\in B$. Then for a $B$-module $F$, we are asking whether the $B$-linear localization map $F\to F\otimes_BB_h=F_h$ is an isomorphism. I would not expect this to happen very often. (For instance if $F=B$ then I do not think one can aim at anything better than injectivity.)

Even with such easy examples I tried to build, the condition I am after seems to fail pretty often for fixed $F$. So, keeping for simplicity the condition that $f$ be an *immersion*, I would like to ask:

> What conditions on $F$ (possibly combined with additional conditions
>   on $f$) make the map $u$ an isomorphism?

*Example*. Take case 2 ($f$ open immersion). Since $\mathcal O_Y\to f_\ast \mathcal O_X$ is an isomorphism when restricted to $X$, I was thinking to fix the previous bug by including the condition that the (scheme-theoretic) support of $F$ is contained in the image of $f$. Would that make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: You are right that in case 2 the map $u$ will only very rarely be surjective. Offhand I can only think of push-forward of coherent sheaves on closed subschemes included in the open subset (cf. my answer). For example a sky-scraper sheaf concentrated on a closed point of the open subset.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: the Proposition in your answer (as well as the last sentence) refers to $f$ closed immersion right? But if $f:X\to Y$ is an open immersion and $X$ is an open neighborhood of the support of $F$, then are you saying $u$ is an isomorphism? In case $Supp(F)\subset X$, $F$ is certainly the pushforward of a sheaf on $X$.

Comment: Yes, the Proposition in my answer concerns a closed subscheme $f:X\hookrightarrow Y$. Suppose now that $i:U\hookrightarrow  Y$ is an open subscheme which happens to contain $X$, namely $j:X\hookrightarrow U$. Now, let $H$ be a quasi-coherent sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-Modules on $X$ and let $G=j_\ast H$, a quasi-coherent sheaf of $\mathcal O_U$-Modules on $U$. The sheaf $F=i_\ast G$ has the required property that $u$ is an isomorphism (to be continued) .

Comment: (Continuation) The sheaf $G$ has indeed support in $X$, but it is not true that any quasi-coherent sheaf on U with support in $X$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-Modules: cf. [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1694206/3217). Hence my prudent formulation in terms of a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$, and not in terms of support.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer in the case of a closed immersion of schemes:

**1) The affine case**
Let $Y=\operatorname {Spec}(A)$ be an affine scheme and let $ F=\widetilde M$ be a quasi-coherent sheaf,  associated to the $A$-module $M$.
 Suppose $X=V(I)=\operatorname {Spec}(A/I)\hookrightarrow Y$ is the closed subscheme associated to the ideal $I\subset A$.
Then the map $F\overset{u}{\longrightarrow}F\otimes_{\mathcal O_Y}f_\ast \mathcal O_X$ corresponds to the $A$-module morphism $$M\overset{v}{\longrightarrow}M\otimes_AA/I=M/IM$$ That map is always surjective and will be injective iff $IM=0$,  which means exactly that $M$ is obtained by restricting scalars to $A$ from an $A/I$-module $N$ i.e. $M=N_{[A]}$.

**2) Globalization: the general case**
Let $Y$ be a scheme, $f: X\hookrightarrow Y$  a closed subscheme and $ F$  a quasi coherent sheaf on $Y$.
**Proposition**
The canonical map $F\longrightarrow F\otimes_{\mathcal O_Y}f_\ast \mathcal O_X $ of quasi-coherent shaves on $Y$ is always surjective.
It is bijective if and only if there exists a quasi-coherent sheaf $E$ on $X$ such that $F=f_\ast(E)$.